# How to prevent Gtk g_source_timeout_add from triggering in multiple instances

Tags: gtk

I register a timeout with:

```
timeout_tag = g_timeout_add(250, update_time, NULL);
```

and destroys it with

```
g_source_remove(timeout_tag);
```

But as I open multiple instances of the same app, the timeout triggers `update_time` in all instances instead of just one. How would I isolate them?

I'm creating a new application with

```
app = gtk_application_new("com.lunacd.reminder", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
```

Should I generate a uuid and append it to `com.lunacd.reminder` so that the identifier remains distinct?

Comment: Are you sure? Though I have not tried this, the instances of the timeouts should be independent! Note that until `source_remove`, the timeout may repeat, depending on the `return` of you handler (TRUE repeats, FALSE stops repeating).

Comment: I tried again and, as you said, can't reproduce this. Thank you for trying it! And sorry for asking a non-existent question. I'm not sure why I saw this behavior before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jcoppens pointed out, timeouts are triggered independently. This question is invalid.